# oracle 12c - select string after last occurrence of a character

Tags: sql, string, oracle, oracle12c

I have below string:

```
ThisSentence.ShouldBe.SplitAfterLastPeriod.Sentence
```

So I want to select `Sentence` since it is the string after the last period. How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can probably do this with complicated regular expressions.  I like the following method:

```
select substr(str, - instr(reverse(str), '.') + 1)
```

Nothing like testing to see that this doesn't work when the string is at the end.  Something about - 0 = 0.  Here is an improvement:

```
select (case when str like '%.' then ''
             else substr(str, - instr(reverse(str), ';') + 1)
        end)
```

EDIT:

Your example works, both when I run it on my local Oracle and in [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/30965).

I am running this code:

```
select (case when str like '%.' then ''
             else substr(str, - instr(reverse(str), '.') + 1)
        end)
from (select 'ThisSentence.ShouldBe.SplitAfterLastPeriod.Sentence' as str from dual) t
```

Answer (score 25):

Just for completeness' sake, here's a solution using regular expressions (not very complicated IMHO :-) ):

```
select regexp_substr(
  'ThisSentence.ShouldBe.SplitAfterLastPeriod.Sentence',
  '[^.]+$') 
from dual
```

The regex

- uses a negated character class to match anything except for a dot `[^.]`
- adds a quantifier `+` to match one or more of these
- uses an anchor `$` to restrict matches to the end of the string

Comment: Found this one very useful. Even more knowing about the fourth parameter for regexp_substr, `ocurrence`. Good answer!

Comment: @Alfabravo did you manage to use it to get the penultimate element?

Comment: I like this solution better, since it is lot more cleaner and simple.

Answer (score 1):

And yet another way.

Not sure from a performance standpoint which would be best...

The difference here is that we use -1 to count backwards to find the last . when doing the instr.

```
  With CTE as 
  (Select 'ThisSentence.ShouldBe.SplitAfterLastPeriod.Sentence' str, length('ThisSentence.ShouldBe.SplitAfterLastPeriod.Sentence') len from dual)
  Select substr(str,instr(str,'.',-1)+1,len-instr(str,'.',-1)+1) from cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  substr(
    'ThisSentence.ShouldBe.SplitAfterLastPeriod.Sentence',  
    INSTR(
      'ThisSentence.ShouldBe.SplitAfterLastPeriod.Sentence',
      '.',
      -1
    )+1
  ) 
from dual;
```

Comment: you can improve your answer by adding comments to it

Answer (score 0):

The `INSTR` function accepts a third parameter, the occurrence. It defaults to 1 (the first occurrence), but also accepts negative numbers (meaning counting from the last occurrence backwards).

```
select substr(str, instr(str, '.', -1) + 1)
from (
    select 'ThisSentence.ShouldBe.SplitAfterLastPeriod.Sentence'
           as str
    from dual);

Sentence
```

Answer (score -1):

how many dots in a string?

```
select length(str) - length(replace(str, '.', '') number_of_dots from ...
```

get substring after last dot:

```
select substr(str, instr(str, '.', 1, number_of_dots)+1) from ...
```