# Oracle PL/SQL: Split string and get last delimited substring

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, split

I am looking for a way to split a string in Oracle PL/SQL and get the last substring separated by the delimiter.

Basically, I have a file-path `/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt` and I want to get a filename.

Most of solutions I find are too long and are basically two step process: split and get the last.

Is there a short way to do this in one step

Comment: Possible duplicate of [oracle 12c - select string after last occurrence of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084644/oracle-12c-select-string-after-last-occurrence-of-a-character)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(filepath, '[^/]+$', 1, 1)
```

This will take all characters after the final delimiter.